# How to execute server's .exe from client in php with xampp

Tags: php, xampp

How do I execute a server's .exe from a client in PHP with xampp??,
I use `exec('C:\xampp\htdocs\test.exe')` but browser always loading .......,
I guess it's a permission issue, but how to bypass the permission to call?

Comment: My answer to it will be and x/y solution, I do not know how to execute via PHP, but you can set it as an `Environment Variable` and execute it from anywhere. Of course, it will be the case in the Windows-only system.

Comment: can you give me a exempled?because i use this to test system('C:^\Windows^\System32^\mspaint.exe');  but it also always loading not to work.My system is Windows server2019

Comment: [If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Permission issues don't cause a program to run forever. My guess is that `test.exe` has some kind of user interface (perhaps it even opens a window) but of course PHP is not designed to interact with other programs as a human would do.

Comment: Yes its has some kind of user interface but ,the exe will auto close when this operating program done,just call exe and give some parameter is ok.but  now i can`t use 
remote to  call anything exe in my server .